# Finding z in the form $a + bi$ when $z^2 = 1 + i + {58\over{9(3-7i)}}$

Tags: complex-numbers

This is a problem from Mathematics Analyses and Approaches HL (IB). Do note that this is not homework or any sort of submission, I'm doing it merely out of interest. This might be trivial for this website, but I've been stuck on it for about thirty minutes now.

The problem statement is as follows:

Given that:
$$
z^2 = 1 + i + {58\over {9(3-7i)}}
$$
find z in the form $ a + bi $
Here's what I've tried so far:
$$
z^2 = {{9(3-7i)} \over {9(3-7i)}} + {{9i(3-7i)} \over {9(3-7i)}} + {58\over {9(3-7i)}}
$$
$$
z^2 = { {9(3-7i) + 9i(3-7i) + 58}\over {9(3-7i)}} * {(3+7i)\over(3+7i)}
$$
$$
z^2 = { {9(58) + 9i(58) + 58(3+7i)}\over {9(58)}}
$$
$$
z^2 = { {9(58) + 9i(58) + 58(3+7i)}\over {9(58)}}
$$
$$
z^2 = { {9 + 9i + 3+7i}\over 9}
$$
$$
z^2 = {12 \over 9} + i{16 \over 9}
$$
I tried taking z as $a + bi $, and then equating $a^2 - b^2$ to $12 \over 9$, and $2abi$ to $i{16 \over 9}$, but that doesn't seem to lead anywhere. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$z^2 =\frac{12}{9}+\frac{16i}{9}=\frac{16}{9}+\frac{16\cdot i}{9}+\frac{4i^2}{9}$$

Comment: oh got it now, thanks a lot!

Comment: But there is no step that how you get it. It is like you get it just from pure luck.

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio, In general, I use your method as well, but here the square is pretty much obvious.

Answer (score 2):

$$z^2=\dfrac{12}{9}+\dfrac{16}{9}i\\z^2=\dfrac{4}{9}(3+4i)\\z=\dfrac{2}{3}\sqrt{3+4i}$$
Let $a+bi=\sqrt{3+4i}$. Set a equation as:
$$\begin{cases} a^2-b^2=3\\2ab=4 \end{cases}$$
From the second equation, we know $a=\dfrac{2}{b}$. Sub this into the first equation and you will solve the answer.

Comment: tried this, too complicated, look at Atticius's answer above

Comment: Although it is complicated, it works for all numbers. If somehow you need to find the square root of $1+2i$, his answer can't work but mine does.

Comment: Btw, I edit it to make the equation be easily to solve.